# ROracle date manipulation

Tags: r, oracle, dbplyr, roracle

I installed ROracle on my computer and successfully connected to a remote Oracle database. I can interact with the tables using dbplyr and collect the data on my computer. But when I try to filter the date columns using dplyr filter function I get error like this:

```
Error in .valueClassTest(ans, "data.frame", "fetch") : invalid value from generic function ‘fetch’, class “try-error”, expected “data.frame”
```

The date columns display as datetime but the lubridate functions do not work (fe converting datetime to date using as_date) on them, but do not throw any error and base-r as.Date throws this error:

```
Error in .oci.SendQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  ORA-00936: missing expression
```

If I collect the data on my computer the datetime columns display correctly and work with all aformentioned functions.

Thank you.

Comment: Please would you add the code that creates the error? It would also help to have the translated database code of the query too. You can use `show_query` to make this.

Comment: Solved by using SQL native function in dplyr pipe (eg. to_date()).

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by using SQL native function in dplyr pipe with right date mask.

```
#setup db connection con... 
tbl(con, "my_tbl") %>%
        filter(Dates_column <= to_date('04.11.2021','DD.MM.YYYY'))
```